# How to implement a resettable, over-ridable, default cell value in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

## >> Question summary

I want to implement a resettable, over-ridable, default cell value in Excel. By this, I mean to have a cell that reverts to a 'default' value, obtained by a lookup formula dependant on a second cell, when that second cell updates. There is also an option for the user to write a different value into the original cell, which would remain until the second cell is next updated.

---

## >> Main body & Details

Okay, so here's the situation; this snapshot is of the relevant area of a multiple worksheet data repository. The two cells of interest are highlighted green for clarity, and the highest visible row is row 1.

- The **Item Search** cell accepts a variety of word or phrase inputs, and has data validation to ensure only valid inputs are possible. The data validation is taken from an alphabetised list of possible inputs, and the cell has a drop-down list option (hence the little arrow to its right).
- The **Stack** cell uses the input from the **Item Search** cell in the following formula...

  ```
  =IF(COUNTIF(C3:F315,J6),VLOOKUP(J6,C3:F315,4,FALSE),"~")
  ```

  ...where J6 is the **Item Search** cell, and the range C3:F315 is the relevant part of a lookup table on the same sheet.

  [image: Snapshot depicting area of Excel document relevant to question.]

Now, this is what I would like to happen in the **Stack** cell...

- Current functionality:

  - When an invalid input is entered into the **Item Search** cell, a tilde is displayed instead of a number.
  - When a valid input is entered, the relevant number from the lookup table is displayed in the cell. The **Buy** and **Sell** cells are also updated in the same fashion.
- Desired additional functionality:

  - In the first instance, the tilde cannot be overwritten.
  - In the second instance, the 'default' number can be overwritten by inputting another number into the **Stack** cell.
  - When a new input is entered (or just the same input again) into the **Item Search** cell, the default number (or the tilde) is then displayed again.
- Wish list (non-essential):

  - To have a check-box (or similar; such as a yes/no input in an adjacent cell) that, if ticked, means that the displayed number in the **Stack** cell will not be changed/affected by any new 'default value' being read in from the lookup table. The number can still be modified by manually entering a new one.
  - The **Item Search** cell currently has a drop-down alphabetised list of all its possible valid data inputs. Is there a way to use this same list to add an auto-complete functionality to the cell? Perhaps a bit like the Google search engine, the drop-down list appears as you type and the items populating that list are continuously limited to those containing the (sub)string that you have so far typed.

*NB: Whatever value is displayed in the **Stack** cell must be readable by formulae in other cells; namely the **Buy** and **Sell** cells, whose values would become a ratio of the **Stack** cell's lookup value and that being displayed in the cell at the time.*

Is this possible to any degree? Preferably (but not exclusively) without needing the use of macros. This workbook is intended to be distributed to other people, with much of it being locked and protected to avoid any changes to the core data.

Thank you in advance.

---

### Information found so far:

...but not quite fully resolving my question.

1. I could probably use more than one cell to achieve the same (or similar) effective functionality (one cell holds the default value, another holds a possible user inputted value, and a third holds the relevant output value), but this would not look as good nor be as intuitive to the end user. This workbook is intended to be distributed to other people with much of it being locked and protected.
   --*This answer is not desirable.*
2. In my internet searchings before asking this question, I turned up this little bit of information. It said that if I wanted the reversion to the default value to be automatic, then use the following code in the worksheet change event routine:

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2")) Is Nothing Then
           If Range("C2").Value = "" Then
               Range("C2").Value = 1234
           End If
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

   However, I am not fully aware of what is meant by this nor how to do it.
   --*C2 is a nominal cell used in the other person's example.*
3. Someone asked a (possibly) similar question and was provided with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585017/how-to-implement-in-excel-if-cell-a1-is-0-cell-a2-foo-else-let-the-user/1585119#1585119) answer to do with using custom number formats. Would a custom number format accept a formula such as the one currently used in the **Stack** cell?

---

### Document upload:

Current and Desired functionality included, Wish list items yet to come.
<strike>[Item-inary (public).xlsm](https://www.mediafire.com/error.php?errno=999&quickkey=wuaat95ojrtbvy1&origin=download) - *(MediaFire)*</strike>
18-Mar-2012, 07:40 UCT

Current and Desired functionality + "Wish list 1".
[Item-inary (public).xlsm](https://www.mediafire.com/file/b4w87f18d7g9t8j/Item-inary_%2528public%2529.xlsm/file) - *(Mediafire)*
20-Mar-2012, 19:50 UCT

---

## >> EDIT #1:

This is my code in its various sections so far:

In `ThisWorkbook`

```
Public temp As Integer 'Used to contain Range("M6").Value once CheckBox5 is ticked
Public warn As Boolean 'True if CheckBox1 is ticked whilst (vVal = "~")

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    warn = False 'Initialise to False
End Sub
```

---

In `Sheet1 (Price List)`

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Value = True Then
        If Range("M6").Value = "~" Then
            warn = True
        Else
            temp = Range("M6").Value
            warn = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim vVal As Variant

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    vVal = Application.Evaluate("=IF(COUNTIF(C3:F315,J6),VLOOKUP(J6,C3:F315,4,FALSE),""~"")")

    '~~> If J6 has been changed, then continue. Otherwise skip.
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J6")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("012370asdf")

        If vVal = "~" Then
            Range("M6").Value = "~"
            Range("M6:M7").Locked = True
        Else
            '~~> Check if CheckBox5 is ticked.
            If OLEObjects("CheckBox5").Object.Value = True Then
                '~~> Checks if CheckBox5 was ticked whilst (vVal = "~")
                If warn = True Then
                    temp = vVal
                    warn = False 'Reset warn status now that special case is resolved
                End If
                Range("M6").Value = temp
            Else
                Range("M6").Value = vVal
            End If
            Range("M6:M7").Locked = False
        End If

        ActiveSheet.Protect ("012370asdf")
        GoTo LetsContinue
    End If

    '~~> If M6 has been changed, then continue. Otherwise skip.
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M6")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        If OLEObjects("CheckBox5").Object.Value = True Then
            temp = Range("M6").Value
        End If

        GoTo LetsContinue
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

This code does not yet include any *'Wish list 2'* functionality, but otherwise works fine.

A big thank you to those who helped.

Comment: +1 For writing such a detailed question!

Comment: +1 Fantastic detail and layout in your question. Seeing the actual file would be useful given the detail you would like applied.

Comment: +1 for nicely explaining the question :) quick question. If the cell J6 has data validation, then how can it have an invalid input?

Comment: Also one suggestion. When using `Worksheet_Change` ALWAYS, use error handling and switch enable events to `False` to avoid  possible endless loop :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Because I've set the error alert to the 'warning' style. This allows the user an option to continue even with an invalid data input. This was for that special someone who either doesn't understand what they're meant to input, or doesn't know the exact spelling of it, and won't appreciate spamming themselves with non-get-around-able 'stop' type error alerts.

Comment: +1 for Detailed question

Comment: @Iakovosian: Could you please confirm if the sample file that I gave worked as per your requirements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> > > @SiddharthRout: I will still upload a current copy of the file for your perusal. Parts of my question have been answered, but there are still the two items from my 'Wish list' to be done with yet! –

As per my earlier suggestion, the current code that you are using should be written as

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J6")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("012370asdf")
        If Application.Evaluate("=IF(COUNTIF(C3:F315,J6),VLOOKUP(J6,C3:F315,4,FALSE),""~"")") = "~" Then
            Range("M6").Value = "~"
            Range("M6:M7").Locked = True
        Else
            Range("M6").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(C3:F315,J6),VLOOKUP(J6,C3:F315,4,FALSE),""~"")"
            Range("M6:M7").Locked = False
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Protect ("012370asdf")
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

This also negates the use of an extra cell N6.

I am looking at the rest of the stuff now and will update it soon.

**UPDATE**: Both your requests in the WishList are complete.

Your `Worksheet_Change` event now becomes this to incorporate Wish List 1 (**See Snapshot attached**)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim vVal As Variant

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    vVal = Application.Evaluate("=IF(COUNTIF(C3:F315,J6),VLOOKUP(J6,C3:F315,4,FALSE),""~"")")

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J6")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("012370asdf")

        '~~> Check the value of the CheckBox and update cells only if false
        '~~> This is valid for "~" as well i.e if the checkbox is Checked then
        '~~> even "~" remain unchanged. If you don't want this, then move the 
        '~~> below condition inside "ELSE" part :)
        If OLEObjects("Checkbox1").Object.Value = False Then
            If vVal = "~" Then
                Range("M6").Value = "~"
                Range("M6:M7").Locked = True
            Else
                Range("M6").Value = vVal
                Range("M6:M7").Locked = False
            End If
        End If

        ActiveSheet.Protect ("012370asdf")
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

For your 2nd Wish List I had two options. I went ahead with the 2nd option.

**1)** Use the method as described in www.ozgrid.com

**Topic: Auto Complete Typing in an Excel Data Validation List**

**Link**: http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/autocomplete-validation.htm

And

**2)** Use a control instead of DV List. For this, I made these changes in the list

- Remove Data validation in Cell J6
- Gave a "Name" to your list X3:X315 from **Name Manager**. I called it "List"
- Placed a ComboBox on top of Cell J6 and set the `.ListFillRange` to the above "List" in design mode
- Added the below code to the worksheet code area

**CODE**

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    Range("J6").Value = ComboBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        Range("J6").Value = ComboBox1.Value
    End If
End Sub`
```

Now your ComboBox will auto-complete whenever you type anything in the box.

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

**SAMPLE FILE LINK (This link is active for 7 days)**

[Sample File](http://wikisend.com/download/511744/Item-inary%20%28public%29.xlsm)

HTH

Sid

Comment: +1 for error handling + enable events + Making the wish come true ;)

Comment: I wasn't able to get back to this until today. For some reason, your sample file doesn't seem to work for me as it does in your snapshot. For one, the combobox doesn't seem to populate. However, the code in your reply and that in your sample file were all very helpful. I've had a play, and the resulting code is shown under **EDIT 1:** in my question.

Comment: Are macros enabled in your pc?

Comment: I've added a snapshot of my current error message. And yes, macros are enabled (unless they also need to be enabled somewhere outside of the options in Excel).

Comment: Are ActiveX Objects Acivated? Which Excel version are you using?

Comment: **ActiveX Settings:** *Prompt me before enabling all controls with minimal restrictions*, and *Safe mode* is ticked. **Macro Settings:** *Disable all macros with notification*, and *Trust access to the VBA project object model* is ticked. **Excel version:** 14.0.6112.5000 (32-bit), Part of Microsoft Office Professional 2010.

Comment: Ok Do this. Unprotect the file and then click on "Design Mode" under the "Developer" tab. Now right click on the Combobox and select "properties". In the properties window that pops up, under "ListFillRange" property, type "List". Close the properties window and exit the "Design Mode". Now check

Comment: Assuming this refers to the sample file you uploaded, I did as instructed - but upon closing and reopening the document, the "ListFillRange" property was cleared.

Comment: Honestly, that is because of my stupidity! Go to the workbook_open code and delete all the code there. That thing is resetting it. I forgot to delete that. My Apologies.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9100/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-iakovosian)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not at my PC right now, so I can't test this but here is what you need to do:

Number 2 in your "Information found so far" is the right direction to go, even though you said that you didn't want macros.

Move your formula for the `Stack` cell into another cell that isn't being used.  Lock this cell, and set the background and text colors to be the same (so that it is "hidden").  For now, let's say that this is in O6.  (Or just have this cell on another sheet that they can not access.  I often have a hidden sheet just for these.)

Right-click on the worksheet tab, and select `View Code`.
In the new window, double-click the worksheet name that you want this code to run on.

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` should be the default function that appears (and it will be empty).

Place the following code into the Worksheet_Change routine:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Range("J6"), Target)

    'If J6 has not been changed, then exit.  Otherwise continue.
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'Replace password with the password that you use to protect the sheet (two places)
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("password")
        If Range("O6").Value = "~" Then
            Range("M6").Value = "~"
            Range("M6:M7").Locked = True
        Else
            Range("M6").Value = Range("O6").Value
            'Use M6:M7 here instead of just M6 because cells are merged.
            Range("M6:M7").Locked = False
        End If 
        ActiveSheet.Protect ("password")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your wish list item can be added to this fairly easily but I will need to be at my PC in order to walk you through how.  That won't be until Monday but maybe someone else can help you with that in the meantime!  The (very) short version though is to add a checkbox control and link it to a cell so that when it is checked it changes the value of the linked cell.  Then you just check the value of that cell before writing the new value to M6.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I have some experience of other programming languages, so I can largely understand what the code is designed to do (it made me smile to see the elegance of your solution). I was able to follow your instructions, but I get an error when it runs; this is to do with changing the 'Locked' property of the 'Range' class.

On a quick look through the related Excel help, I enabled access to the VBA project object model but this didn't seem to be the answer. Perhaps the property has a slightly different name? I will have a look.

I am running Excel 2010.

Comment: Just realised I need to put my actual lock/unlock password in place of the words! Also I tried changing one of the lines to `Me.Protect ("password"), userinterfaceonly:=True`, based on what I read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/447247/1276419). I also assume the last line was mean to be `End Sub`. Still getting the runtime error '1004'.

Comment: I copied some code that used Me. I have updated it to use ActiveSheet as it should.

Comment: If you use userinterfaceonly, then you can remove the Unprotected/Protect calls all together (but where you DO protect it, you must use that option.) the reason that I didn't use it was so that you could protect it from the normal excel menu as well since you stated in your question that it was already protected.

Comment: Another quick response, thank you. Still getting the runtime error '1004' relating to the `Range("M6").Locked = False` line. I'm learning a lot just from searching and trying to find what it doesn't like, but it's still not completely happy.

Comment: The exact words are `Unable to set the Locked property of the Range class`. I've not been able to discover anything more about what's actually causing it. Goodnight!

Comment: Okay, figured it out: since your cells are merged, you must use the full range which includes all of the merged cells when locking and unlocking.  So, change M6 to M6:M7 for both lock commands.